# Create JSON from another JSON with duplicate values in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON:

```
[{'job': 'fireman', 'salary': 30000', 'country':'USA'}, {'job': 'doctor', 'salary': '50000': 'country': 'Canada'},{'job': 'fireman', 'salary': 60000', 'country':'France'}, {'job': 'Engineer', 'salary': 45000', 'country':'Mexico'} ]
```

I want to combine the duplicate values and create a JSON like:

```
[

{"job": "fireman",

"sumamry": [{"country": "USA", "Salary": 40000}, {"Country": "France", "Salary": 60000}]

"total" : 100000},

{"job": "doctor",

"summary": [{"country": "Canada", "Salary": 50000}]

"total" : 50000},

....
]
```

Comment: JSON is a python dict once it is loaded. dict has a method `update` which you can use to combine two dicts, once the JSON file is opened and loaded. Then you can dump the updated dict back into the JSON file in 'w' mode.

Comment: I know that but how do I combine the duplicate values, in this case fireman, so that I can create a sub dict of country and salary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
non_summarized = [{'job': 'fireman', 'salary': 30000, 'country':'USA'}, {'job': 'doctor', 'salary': 50000, 'country': 'Canada'},{'job': 'fireman', 'salary': 60000, 'country':'France'}, {'job': 'Engineer', 'salary': 45000, 'country':'Mexico'}]

# sort the list of dictionary base on job keys, so we can loop in the order
non_summarized = sorted(non_summarized, key = lambda i: i['job'])

summarized = list()
last_value = dict()

for d in non_summarized:
  # check if the last value has the same job or not
  # if not then create a new dict value and update with new information
  if last_value.get('job') != d.get('job'):

    last_value = {
      'job': d.get('job'),
      'total': 0,
      'summary': list()
    }
    summarized.append(last_value)

  last_value['total'] += d.get('salary', 0)
  last_value['summary'].append({
    'country': d.get('country'), 
    'salary': d.get('salary')
    })

print(summarized)
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thank you this answer worked and it is quite clear.